# duplicate records displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Why is duplicate content displaying when I run my code? I am using empty() to remove the previous records on re-run, but it doesn't seems to be working either.

Here is my code:

```
function listClass() {
this.formOrderList = null;
this.orderListDialogObject = $('<div id="mainDiv"></div>');
this.orderListTable = $('<div>'
    + '<table id="orderListTable" class="ui-widget tblBorder" width="100%" border="0"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">'
    + '<thead class="ui-widget-header" id="orderListHead">' + '<tr>'
    + '<th><strong> Order# </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Symbol </strong></th>'
    //+ '<th><strong> Exchange </strong></th>'
    //+ '<th><strong> Market </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Time </strong></th>'            
    + '<th><strong> Order Type </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Side </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Volume </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Price </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Trigger Price </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Filled Volume </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Status </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Expiry Date </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Ref # </strong></th>'
    + '<th><strong> Action </strong></th>' + '</tr>' + '</thead>'
    + '<tbody id="orderListBody">' + '</tbody>' + '</table>' + '</div>');
this.orderListTabs = $('<div>' + '<ul>'
    + '<li><a href="#pendingOrderList">Pending</a></li>' + '</ul>'
    + '<div id="pendingOrderList">' + '</div>' + '</div>');
this.orderListDialogObject.appendTo("body");
this.show = function() {
$("#orderListBody", this.orderListTable).empty();
this.orderListDialogObject.dialog({
    title : 'Order List',
    width : 850,
    height : 150,           
    close : function(ev, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
        return false;
        /*$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        return false;*/
    }
});
this.orderListTabs.tabs();
this.orderListTabs.appendTo(this.orderListDialogObject);        
$("#pendingOrderList", this.orderListTabs).append(this.orderListTable);
}
```

Comment: I have built [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/pnNNU/) with your code, but can't [see](http://jsfiddle.net/pnNNU/show/) duplicate content.

Comment: scessor not in thead, in tbody it displays duplicate contents.

Comment: And which functions fills the `tbody`? In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pnNNU/1/show/) ([here with code](http://jsfiddle.net/pnNNU/1/)) you see an example with filled `tbody` and no problem with duplicate content.

Comment: scessor it was working fine before, i dont know why it is not working now. I have to see it again.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing `this` inside a function, so it's pointing to the global object.

Here's a workaround:

```
var that = this;
this.show = function() {
$("#orderListBody", that.orderListTable).empty();
that.orderListDialogObject.dialog({
    title : 'Order List',
    width : 850,
    height : 150,           
    close : function(ev, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
        return false;
        /*$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        return false;*/
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm aware. but you're referencing `this` inside an anonymous function which has no binding to your class. Therefore `this` will point to the global object, likely `window`.